# Postgresql Trigger failed error

Tags: postgresql

I created a trigger when I run trigger I get an error. When I insert a data to adpes.add_project table. I want to run the trigger. But I get an error. How can I solve this problem? The error is

> Failed to execute SQL. Error: ERROR: function st_point(double precision, double precision) does not exist LINE 1: ...s.adpes_project SET geom= st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(n... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. QUERY: UPDATE adpes.adpes_project SET geom= st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(new.project_lng::double precision,new.project_lat::double precision),4326),500000) CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function add_project_2() line 3 at SQL statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION adpes.add_project_2()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE adpes.adpes_project SET geom= st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(project_lng::double precision,project_lat::double precision),4326),500000);
    UPDATE adpes.adpes_project t1 SET  k1k = t2.fish_id from spatial.fish_net_k1k t2 where st_intersects(t1.geom,t2.geom);
    UPDATE adpes.adpes_project t1 SET  k20k = t2.fish_id from spatial.fish_net_k20k t2 where st_intersects(t1.geom,t2.geom);
    UPDATE adpes.adpes_project t1 SET  pro_cluster_id =  (id::Text || ''  || k20k::Text)::bigint ;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION adpes.add_project_2()
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TRIGGER add_project_2
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON adpes.adpes_project
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE adpes.add_project_2();
```

Comment: do you have postgis installed?

Comment: yes I installed

Comment: if you just try to execute this : select st_point(10::float,20::float)   what happens ?

Comment: I get same error.